# Draw Oval to array

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

Hopefully this'll be a fairly simple answer, but it's not the easiest thing to google for.

I'm planning to do a lot of painting using simple shapes, but the actual result doesn't need to be displayed to the user until the final stage, so for the sake of speed, I was wondering if there were existing methods in c#/WPF to draw simple shapes to a buffer without the overhead of a BitmapSource, so at the end I can just copy it into a WritableBitmap.

Something like

```
PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
int stride = bitmapWidth * pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel / 8;
byte[] pixels new byte[bitmapHeight * stride];
*some static library*.DrawOval(xpos=10,ypos=10,radius=5, pixels, stride, pixelFormat);
```

Thanks

Comment: A bitmap already is an array internally.  You are not going to speed that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Drawing shapes to a buffer" in WPF could be done by drawing shapes into a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) using a [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx). When drawing is finished, the DrawingVisual can be rendered into a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).

Example:

```
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(100, 100), 50, 50);
}

Drawing drawing = drawingVisual.Drawing;

using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawDrawing(drawing);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(100, 100), 60, 60);
}

RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I want to be able to draw the shapes, then copy the pixels, do some processing and then come back and draw some more shapes on top if needed. If I reopen the DrawingVisual for painting, I have to redraw all the shapes... if I understand correctly. Otherwise the DC is reset to blank when reopened.

Comment: All drawings in a DrawingVisual are accessible by its [Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.drawing.aspx) property. This "root drawing" can be drawn again into a new DrawingContext by [DrawDrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawdrawing.aspx) before drawing more. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that property then. Thanks for your answer. I think this'll do me just fine.